# Does the digital copy of Tekken Tag Tournament 2 include an online pass?

Tags: ps3, psn, tekken, tekken-tag-tournament-2

Currently there is a digital promotion on [Tekken Tag Tournament 2](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-gb/games/tekken-tag-tournament-2/cid=EP0700-NPEB01140_00-TEKKENTAG2DLGAME) for only 3.99GBP on the UK psn store. I am wondering though. Does this include an online pass?

The description says that this is the full game. But in the PSN store an online pass is sold separately for 7.99GBP.
Does anyone know if this includes the online pass? I need it in order to get some online trophies but if I can get the full game cheaper I can easily get it and sell my physical copy to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says "Full game", then it is full game.

Online passes are sold because some people buy 2nd hand games(or borrow them for undefined time) which do not have a valid pass anymore, so to play online they will have to buy online pass.

**EDIT**

To make sure that you are sure I will add some more info. According to [this link](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-hu/games/tekken-tag-tournament-2/cid=EP0700-NPEB01140_00-TEKKENTAG2DLGAME), it is the full game. Quote from there:

> NOTE: This game's downloadable content is the same as the packaged version, and **includes the online pass** but none of the pre-order downloadable content.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I am getting that you are answering yes, but not sure :P

Comment: @JohnDemetriou added some info. Are you sure now? :)